# multiple views are effecting, ListView android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have ListView with 8 (4 visible) List items on it. each view contains one TextView and one ImageView (initially set to transparent). now am trying to set img to imageView from onItemClick method. Its working fine for me, but when i scroll down some other view also effecting. for example if i select 0th position item, both 0th and 4th position views are setting to same img. how can i resolve this.

java code:

```
list.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this,
            application.distanceList, R.layout.drop_down_view, from, to));
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            try {
                ((ImageView) temp.findViewById(R.id.ddviv))
                        .setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }
            ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ddviv))
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.drop_sel);
            temp = v;}
    });
```

Comment: Are you using CustomAdapter for List? If yes then provide getView() code. If not then implement it.

Comment: You are right, this type of problem occurs many times in `ListView`

Comment: Better would be posting the Adapter class code.

Comment: Implement CustomAdapter instead of SimpleAdapter and in getView() of adapter  put condition of applying image with if - else for particular position.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Custom Adapter (extending `BaseAdapter` is a good choice) with `ViewHolder`s inside your `getView()` method. When you click, you change some attributes and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

If you don't know how to implement a custom Adapter, [Google](http://goo.gl/dXhNS) has a lot of tuts =)

Comment: in my application, i have so many different list views like this. I am not interested to create Custom adapter for all. is any other way to do this

Comment: @Babloo why don't you use the same Custom Adapter class for all the same listViews ? I don't get you

Comment: my requirement is same, but list items or different. In this case i have 1 TextView and 1 ImageView, but in other case i have some extra items too.

Comment: @Babloo then you can create a generic custom adapter, and extend it for your other lists.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to set those images from the `ListView`'s rows is to make some data adjustments and also use a `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder`. I don't know how you set the data for the row views(I can't see what you have in the `from` and `to` arrays) or what do you have in the `application.distanceList` so here is a small example. First of all in each `Map` from the `application.distanceList`(corresponding to a `ListView` row) you'll have to add an entry like this:

```
map.put("position", "x"); // where x is the list row number(for the first Map in application.distanceList x will be 0, for the second Map in application.distanceList x will be 1 etc)
```

You'll include the `"position"` in the `from` array and corresponding to this `"position"` you'll put the id of the `ImageView` from the row layout in the `to` array.

Next, you'll have to add a `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder` to bind the image in the `ListView` row(this will handle the `ListView`'s recycle mechanism):

```
mAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                    String textRepresentation) {
                            // view is the ImageView from the row layout
                            // data is the x from the position column
                if (view.getId() == R.id.imageView1) {
                    Integer rowNumber = Integer.parseInt((String) data);
                                    // below is the explanation for mImageIds
                    ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(mImageIds[rowNumber]);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The `mImageIds` is an array of `ints` that will hold the id of the drawable for the `ListView`'s rows:

```
// a field in your class
private int[] mImageIds = new int[8]; // you said you had 8 rows

//.. in the onCreate method initialize the mImageIds array

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        mImageIds[j] = R.drawable.ic_launcher;// a default image(you could use android.R.color.transparent for empty)
    }
```

Finally in the `onItemClick` callback:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
       mImageIds[position] = android.R.drawable.btn_minus; // the desired image
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This sound more complicated then it is, I hope you understand the principle, the other solution is to build a custom adapter like other users already said.